# Getting wrong result in Prettydate

Tags: javascript

[jsffiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm6e8qyL/1/)

If I pass current time and date still it shows `5 Hours`
Current time is `2015-06-17T17:18:17Z` and I passed `2015-06-17T16:40:17Z`.. ..What is the problem..please suggest me

Comment: what should it display??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part made the code appear as if it was two hours behind

```
var time = ('' + date_str).replace(/-/g, "/").replace(/[TZ]/g, " "),
        dt = new Date,
        seconds = ((dt - new Date(time) + (dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)) / 1000),
        token = ' Ago',
        i = 0,
        format;
```

I found out that getTimezoneOffset adds `-120` to the current seconds, so I changed it into:

```
var time = ('' + date_str).replace(/-/g, "/").replace(/[TZ]/g, " "),
        dt = new Date,
        seconds = ((dt - new Date(time) + (60000)) / 1000),
        token = ' Ago',
        i = 0,
        format;
```

It seemed somewhat precise, even though it almost always says either `just now` or `x hour(s) (ago)`

Could you please elaborate what this function is supposed to do?

Comment: It display like `Just now` or `2 Minutes ago` according to given time but the problem is I passed current time still its display `5 Hours`..